# Bash Loop that changes output file name

Tags: bash, loops, terminal, alias

I have a bash alias that converts .mov to .gif
I have a folder of .mov, and I want to execute the alias on every file in the folder
I have a loop that works, it runs through and converts each file in the folder, but it (prompts me to) overwrites each filename.

```
alias video_to_gif='function video_to_gif(){ ffmpeg -i $1 output.gif && gifsicle -O3 output.gif -o output.gif && say "Video is ready!"};video_to_gif'


for file in *.mov
do
video_to_gif $file
done
```

I need to add an instruction to the loop that changes the file name for every file it converts(to anything, as long as they are different for every file)

At the moment if I have n files in the folder, it will run through and convert every one, but the folder will have n+1 files at the end, with the one converted file being the conversion of the last original file

Comment: Why do you need an alias for that? What's wrong with defining that function in your bashrc?

Comment: @hughm-01 : Whats the point in having an alias which **creates** a function? This is kind of bizarre...

Comment: There's a point to doing that with git aliases, but that's a git-specific thing; it doesn't apply anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just changing the extension from `.mov` to `.gif` for each input file should be sufficient in your case.

By the way: You don't need the alias, especially since you already wrote a function:

```
video_to_gif() {
    out="${1%.*}.gif"
    ffmpeg -i "$1" "$out" &&
    gifsicle -O3 "$out" -o "$out"
    && say "Video is ready!"
}
for file in *.mov; do
    video_to_gif "$file"
done
```